# transform julian day with decimal to date and hour in R

Tags: r, database, date, transformation, julian-date

I have to convert on R a column with julian dates with decimal part (as parts of the day) to date and hour.

I tried this function :
`as.Date(10625.15, origin=as.Date("1990-01-01 00:00:00"))`

But it only gave me the date without the times :
`"2019-02-02"`

Someone can help me to resolve it ? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

You used `as.Date` and it returned a date, exactly what it is designed to do (ref: [`?as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) says it will *return an object of class "Date"*). Fortunately, it returns a fractional date:

```r
dput(as.Date(10625.15, origin=as.Date("1990-01-01 00:00:00")))
# structure(17930.15, class = "Date")
###              ^^^ yay! we have fraction
```

so we can wrap it in `as.POSIXct`:

```r
as.POSIXct(as.Date(10625.15, origin=as.Date("1990-01-01 00:00:00")))
# [1] "2019-02-02 22:36:00 EST"
```

Timezone notwithstanding. `.15` of a day is 3.6 hours, so with converting to UTC above, this would show `03:36:00`.

One might be tempted to use `as.POSIXct` *in place of* `as.Date`, though realize that `10625.15` is in fractional days, not fractional seconds (which is what `as.POSIXct` will expect). To do that, you need to convert from "days" to "seconds":

```r
as.POSIXct(86400*10625.15, origin=as.Date("1990-01-01 00:00:00"))
# [1] "2019-02-02 22:36:00 EST"
```